# Do these two permutations generate $A_n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-presentation

Let $n$ be odd  and not a multiple of $3$. Do the cycle $\sigma:=(1, 2, \dots, n)$ and any cycle of length $3$ generate $A_n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$No.

$$
\Span{(1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots,35), (1,6,11)}
$$
is not the alternating group on $35$ letters.

The reason is that it is imprimitive. A block is
$$
\Set{1,6,11,16,21,26,31}
$$

Comment: Is this the smallest counterexample?

Comment: If the group $G$ generated by the two permutations is primitive, Jordan's theorem kicks in. So we need $n$ to be composite, in order to have blocks. Come to think of it, $n = 25$ would do as well, and that would be smallest possible. Will leave the example as it is, though. And many thanks for the useful question.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I won't forget that trick!

Comment: @doubleCat, thanks, I appreciate.